# Return Text to the last instance of a hyphen "TEXTBEFORE" not available

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a number of different roles in column 1.  Role names are made up of the role title, sometimes a sub title and the city and state the role is located.  Example "Associate - [city, state]"  vs  "Associate - [sub title] -[city, state]."

```
Associate - New York, NY
Associate - Flexible -New York, NY
Associate - San Francisco, CA
Associate - Flexible - San Francisco, CA
```

How do I retrieve the text in front of the last hyphen.  I've found formulas that allow me to pull either Associate, or New York, NY.  But none that will retrieve both Associate and Associate -Flexible removing the New York, NY (city and state).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))),1)-2)
```

[image]

**Edit:** As discussed in the comments, the `@` sign is used to replace the `-` sign to find the last occurrence. If the string already contains an `@` sign, for e.g. in an email address, then use another character that does not occur in the cell. Also, if you're using European settings, your computer may use the semicolon to separate parameters in formulas instead of the comma.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: What is the @'s.  Thank you for the suggestion but I'm getting an error message #VALUE!.  Is this possibly due to not having the same version of excel or needing to change General to Text or Number?

Comment: You shouldn't get an error due to version number - all those functions have been in Excel for as long as I can remember.  If you break the formula down you'll find where the error is:  `LEN` will return the number of characters in a cell, `SUBSTITUTE` will replace a character in a string with another, so `=LEN(A1)` returns 25, `=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))` replaces the hyphen with an empty string and calculates the length which will be 24.  Minus one value from the other will tell you there's one hyphen in A1.

Comment: `SUBSTITUTE` allows you to substitute a specified instance of the hyphen, which is the value returned by the `LEN` part of the formula.  So the last instance of the hyphen is replaced with a `@` - a value that's not likely to appear in your text.  Excel is now seeing the text as "Associate @ New York, NY" or "Associate - Flexible @ New York, NY".

Comment: Next `FIND` is used to look for that `@` sign and returns its position.  Hard-coded it's saying `=FIND("@","Associate  @  New York, NY",1)`.  This will return 12 as @ is the twelth character. `LEFT` will return the first twelve characters from the text:  "Associate  -".  The final -2 tells LEFT to take into account the hyphen and the space, so only keep the first ten characters.

Comment: So.... an error is likely to occur if your text already contains a `@` symbol (in which case use a different symbol like an `|` bar), doesn't contain a `-` at all or only contains a `-` and nothing else.  Maybe I should have put all that as an edit to the answer that teylyn gave... with permission of course.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes, you can edit my answer and improve it. That's how this site works.